# How to combine multiple lists and use as a GridView datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

ASP.net:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSP" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
</asp:GridView>
```

Code-behind:

```
lstName.Add(lstN[f]); //name
lstCMSID.Add(lstNum[f]); //number
lstSpecialtyPhys.Add(data.Text.ToString()); //value
```

I would like to combine the three List and display it in the above GridView, like this:

```
Name                        Number              Value
John Doe                    56                  90
James Coon                  34                  24
```

How can I achieve the above so there are three columns with three different header text.

Comment: There's millions of examples on the net.  What exactly are you having a problem with? BoundField is one option.

Comment: The question I have and what I am unsure of how do I set all three list to be in one GridView with custom header text?

Comment: Create a DataTable from your lists and assign the GridView.DataSource = to your datatable.  An example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331388/from-array-to-datatable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way would be to do a loop (a for, foreach, etc)

```
        List<dynamic> lstName = new List<dynamic>();
        List<dynamic> lstCMSID = new List<dynamic>();
        List<dynamic> lstSpecialtyPhys = new List<dynamic>();

        lstName.Add("John Doe");
        lstCMSID.Add("56");
        lstSpecialtyPhys.Add("90");

        lstName.Add("James Coon");
        lstCMSID.Add("34");
        lstSpecialtyPhys.Add("24");

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Number");
        dt.Columns.Add("Value");

        for (int i = 0; i < lstName.Count; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(lstName[i], lstCMSID[i], lstSpecialtyPhys[i]);
        }

        gvSP.DataSource = dt;
        gvSP.DataBind();
```

Comment: WOW how simple and easy. THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU :) +1 and accepted.

Answer (score 1):

create a class as

```
private class ABC{  
string name ="";  
int number=0,val=0;  
    public string name1 {
    get { return name; }
    set { name = value; }
}
public int number1 {
    get { return number; }
    set { number = value; }
}
public int value1 {
    get { return val; }
    set { val = value; }
}
}
```

Add the below code in the code behind

```
var source = new BindingSource();
ArrayList dataobj = new ArrayList();
ABC obj = new ABC();
obj.name="Sample"  
obj.number=1
obj.value=5 
dataobj.add(obj);  
source.DataSource = dataobj;
DataGrid.DataSource = source;
DataGrid.Columns(0).Name="Desired Name" // So On for the Rest, to set desired name to the header
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I am confused as to how to complete it. :/

Comment: Confused?? OK No Problem Will Help is it possible to send your code behind srikanth.suryadevara@live.com  
Hope I may Find a Solution.

Comment: Well I posted the three lists that I have. Just need to add it to a datatable with custom column name :)

Comment: You have both the options to do with a datatable approach which requires an assemply import and dataobject approach which requires a small class with get set methods. I will edit my answer you will get it

Comment: I have something like this: `var allProducts = lstName.Concat(lstCMSID)
         .Concat(lstSpecialtyPhys)
         .ToList();` which adds it to the GridView but as one column. I would like to split them into three separate columns.

Comment: You have to mention in the question that the solution has to be based on datatable :-(

Comment: It doesn't have to be but the solution was simple and easy and worked :). I did +1 your answer for starting the process out :) Thank you.

Comment: I am not blaming i am just suggesting to be specific that's it no more controversy , thanks for that ...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `DataTable` and put your data in it then bind the table to your grid.

Comment: That's what I would like some help on :)